# Get user in WebApi from MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

I use standard SPA Visual Studio 2013 template and it's Identity system on MVC Controllers. All user information is accessable on HomeController. But how can I fetch loggined user ID in ApiController?

Any alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ApiController` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) has a [`User` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.user%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) that can be used in the same way that a regular `Controller.User` is used.

Comment: But it always **null**. I can't' retrive necessary info from it.

Comment: Can you show how you are setting our User when logging in?

Comment: var id = User.Identity.GetUserId(); This works in HomeController but not in ApiController. Suspect that it's two different, isolatet things.

Comment: How are you **setting** your `User` on login? Are do you have a line like `FormsAuthentication.SignIn(userName)`? Something else?

Comment: Only default solution in AccountController. Do you mean AuthenticationManager.SignIn method?

Comment: Yes. Do you have a line somewhere like `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` or `FormsAuthentication.SignIn()` during your login procesure?

Comment: Searhing in project shows only this result in web.config   '' <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>''

Comment: So nothigs useful I foud like FormsAuthentication. What should I do?